# Getting process ID with java apache default executor

Tags: java, apache-commons-exec

I'm writing a code that runs a commandline using default executor of apache.
I found the way to get the exit code but I couldn't found the way to get the process ID.

my code is:

```
protected void runCommandLine(OutputStream stdOutStream, OutputStream stdErrStream, CommandLine commandLine) throws InnerException{
DefaultExecutor executor = new DefaultExecutor();
    PumpStreamHandler streamHandler = new PumpStreamHandler(stdOutStream,
            stdErrStream);
    executor.setStreamHandler(streamHandler);
    Map<String, String> environment = createEnvironmentMap();
try {
        returnValue = executor.execute(commandLine, environment);
    } catch (ExecuteException e) {
       // and so on...
        }
        returnValue = e.getExitValue();
        throw new InnerException("Execution problem: "+e.getMessage(),e);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        throw new InnerException("IO exception while running command line:"
                + ioe.getMessage(),ioe);
    }
}
```

What should i do in order to get the ProcessID?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5174426/graceful-kill-of-apache-commons-exec-process).

Comment: Im working with Windows...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to retrieve the PID of the process using the apache-commons API (nor using the underlying [Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html)).

The "simplest" thing would probably be to have your external program executed in such a way that the program itself returns its PID somehow in the output it generates.  That way you can capture it in your java app.

It's a shame java doesn't export the PID. It has been a feature-request for [over a decade](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4244896).

Comment: For example, this will cause the PID to be the first line printed : `/bin/sh -c 'echo $$ && exec program args'`

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to retrieve the PID for a Process object in Java 9 and later. However to get to a Process instance in Apache Commons Exec you will need to use some non-documented internals.

Here's a piece of code that works with Commons Exec 1.3:

```
DefaultExecutor executor = new DefaultExecutor() {
    @Override
    protected Process launch(final CommandLine command, final Map<String, String> env, final File dir) throws IOException {
        Process process = super.launch(command, env, dir);
        long pid = process.pid();
        // Do stuff with the PID here... 
        return process;
    }
};
// Build an instance of CommandLine here
executor.execute(commandLine);
```